# center psuedo element content

Tags: html, css

I have a little "caret" that is put on my currently hovered menu item ,and I now realize the caret created it not centered. I have a bunch of dynamically sized menu items.

The class `menu-caret` is applied when hovered by a little bit of jquery, and I have some css like so :

```
.menu-caret::before {
content:"";
position: absolute;
margin-left: 20px;
bottom: 0;
width: 0%;
height: 0;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

See a quick example here - https://jsfiddle.net/keL4zhky/3/.

Is it possible to have the carets be centered on the bottom? Thanks!

**EDIT**: is it possible to do this without relative? I have a full width sub menu that if i change the ul/li to relative will lose it's effect - See example here http://codepen.io/ajmajma/pen/KgGxWL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make the parent `position: relative;` and add `left: 50%;` and `margin-left: -5px;` to the pseudo element:

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.menu-caret::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="menu-caret">one</li>
  <li class="menu-caret">larger</li>
  <li class="menu-caret">larrrrger</li>
</ul>
```

Instead of `left: 50%;` and `margin-left: -5px;`
you can also just use `left: calc(50% - 5px);`

Answer (score 2):

The `li` has to have `position:relative` to provide positioning context.

The pseudo-element is then positioned absolutely 50% left and then pulled back 50% of **it's own width** by the transform. This will work for *any size caret* and does not require any magic numbers.

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.menu-caret {
  position: relative;
}
.menu-caret::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="menu-caret">one</li>
  <li class="menu-caret">larger</li>
  <li class="menu-caret">larrrrger</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: IS there a way around this without setting the ul or li to relative? I have a hide/show sub menu that is getting messed with when I do this. I will post a fiddle update

Comment: Not really...unfortunately, the caret has to be positioned in relation to it's parent and that requires `position:relative`. Hide/show shouldn't make any difference. I'd suggest you ask a NEW question in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `absolute` positioning and `float`, I prefer:

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
}
 
 .menu-caret::after {
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
   content: "";
   border-left: 5px solid transparent;
   border-right: 5px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 5px solid black;
   clear: both;
   width: 1px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="menu-caret">one</li>
<li class="menu-caret">larger</li>
<li class="menu-caret">larrrrger</li>
</ul>
```